# Socket.io and express.js, how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've seen many variations online but nothing seems to be working for me. How to get socket.io 1.3.5 and express 4.12.2 to work?

This is what I have right now. The error I get is 404 because the server can't serve `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

app.js:

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('connected');
});
```

index.hjs:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
          var socket = io.connect();
          socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
</script>
```

**NOTE:** I've also tried to use the cdn `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>` but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use socket.io with express we have required some changes in default confiscation of expesss.

> app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

module.exports = app;
```

> io.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

module.exports = io;
```

> bin/www:

```
var app = require('../app');
var io = require('../io');
var server = require('http').Server(app);

io.attach(server);
server.listen(8080);
```

Now for index template you should use like following

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });

      });
});
</script>
```

Its a working code..

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! seems like all I was missing was io.attach(server).